# Internal and external DTD subsets, each in its own XML namespace

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

An old C++ programmer but new to XML, I wish to layer my own, internally defined DTD upon the existing SVG DVD.  Knowing no better, I would do so in this manner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:foo=[ <!-- My DTD here. --> ]>
    <!-- Mixed SVG and FOO markup here. -->
</svg>
```

Even I can see that my approach is naive, nor did I expect it to work, but hours spent reading [W3C's](http://www.w3.org/) XML and XMLNS recommendations have not taught me the right way to do it.  Can you?

Comment: Namespaces don't actually define a schema or DTD, they just identify that a document is a mixture of formats defined separately; a namespace is just an arbitrary URI used as a global identifier. In fact, very few XML formats in my experience have a DTD, usually a schema definition in XSD or RelaxNG format is used. If you need your resulting file to validate against a tool using DTDs, then I'm not actually sure how that works.

Comment: I agree with @IMSoP. You really should use XSD or RelaxNG rather than DTD, especially if you're using namespaces, which can only be made to work with DTDs through unnatural contortions.

Comment: I see.  I must learn XSD or RelaxNG, of neither of which I knew.  This would indeed explain why I was having such trouble giving my DTD a namespace.

Comment: You should.  RelaxNG is more elegant; XSD, more widely used.  Both are better than DTD at this point in XML's evolution, especially where namespaces are involved.

Comment: @kjhughes:  If you posted your comments as an answer, I should naturally be pleased to upvote it.

Comment: @IMSoP:  If it matters to you, if you posted your comment as an answer, then of course I should upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DTDs served XML well in the early days and SGML well before that, but trying to shoehorn modern schema requirements of XML, especially involving relatively newer namespaces, into DTDs is not recommended.

Both XSD and RelaxNG would be better for expressing XML vocabulary and grammar constraints at this point in XML's evolution, especially where namespaces are involved.

**I recommend you use RelaxNG or XSD for your namespaced XML schema needs.**

<sup><sub>[Personal opinion: RelaxNG is more elegant.  XSD is more widely used.  I only end up using RelaxNG internally or when I'm sure that my group is with me in appreciating RelaxNG.  Politically, XSD is a safer bet with its W3C backing.  Many groups will select XSD but avoid its more esoteric elements.]</sub></sup>

Comment: Regarding the choice of RelaxNG or XSD, there are tools which can automatically convert (a restricted subset of?) one into the other, so it would be possible to author using RelaxNG but still publish an XSD for those who wish to validate against it.